# Overlay a plot of sensor readings on video output

Tags: video, sensor, raspicam, streaming-video

I'm working on a project where I use a Pi + camera + sensors. I would like to use the picamera module and overlay a moving plot of the real-time sensor readings on the video output by using the picamera.add_overlay(sensor readings)....

Im thinking of using matplotlib to generate a cumulative readings.jpg file every second and then use that as the overlay. Would this method work ?

Stretch goal would be to output to a network stream but am not sure if picamera supports this level of overlay. Ive seen somewhere that it works only for preview - so am a bit confused.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [issue #196](https://github.com/waveform80/picamera/issues/196) on picamera's github - that goes into detail of why overlays are only supported on preview at the moment.

Comment: You want something like this? http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=16#example9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried different approaches to do this but finally settled on using picamera's add_overlay function to overlay an "image" of a graph of the sensor readings. I believe you can use pygame to develop a more fully functional result but this worked for me.

In a nutshell, I  generated saved the output of a matplotlib graph of the sensor readings to the same image file. I then use picamera's add_overlay and update overlay functions to update the image-graph.

I documented how to do this here with a link to code

https://medium.com/a-r-g-o/argo-nyc-big-apps-2015-7c565eec4c60

Comment: While technically an answer, link only answers are usually frowned upon in the stack exchange community. Links to your own site are seen as traffic fishing, and links in general are susceptible to link rot. Please do consider including the answer in your post.

Comment: ...and that link is gone.. :(

Comment: @Edward I have updated the link. Thanks for flagging!